# Call to undefined method create() error

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, orm

I want to save my images with using save_image() function in media model..

Here is my media model;

```
class Media extends Model
{
public function save_image($file)
    {
        $realname = str_slug(pathinfo($file->getClientOriginalName(), PATHINFO_FILENAME));
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $new_name = str_slug($realname) . "-" . time() . "." . $extension;
        $file->move(public_path('uploads'), $new_name);

        $image = DB::create([
            'image' => $new_name,
            'image_path' => "uploads/" . $new_name,
            'image_alt_name' => $realname
        ]);
        return $image;
    }
}
```

in my controller;

```
public function storeMedia(Request $request)

{
    $this->validate($request,[
        'image'=> 'required|mimes:jps,png,gif,jpeg'
    ]);

    $image=$request->file('image');
    $media = new Media();
    $media->save_image($image);

    return response()->json([
        'url'=> env('APP_URL')."/".$image->image_path,
        'alt' => $image->image_alt_name,
        'id' => $image->id,
    ]);
}
```

Are we have to say `DB::table('media')` at the first ? I mean, we are already on media model, is that necesary ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not specifying the table name in your code.

Here is the Solution

```
$image = DB::table('media')->create([
        'image' => $new_name,
        'image_path' => "uploads/" . $new_name,
        'image_alt_name' => $realname
    ]);
```

**OR**

```
$image = Media::create([
        'image' => $new_name,
        'image_path' => "uploads/" . $new_name,
        'image_alt_name' => $realname
    ]);
```

You can also use `$this->create`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Query builder doesn't have `create()` method, so you need to use Eloquent:

```
Model::create([
    'image' => $new_name,
    'image_path' => "uploads/" . $new_name,
    'image_alt_name' => $realname
]);
```

If you want to use query builder, you can use the `insert()` method:

```
DB::table('table_name')->insert([
    'image' => $new_name,
    'image_path' => "uploads/" . $new_name,
    'image_alt_name' => $realname
]);
```